# Should I persist consolidated sums in a separate table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I am developing a C# application working with millions of records retrieved from a relational database (SQL Server). My main table "Positions" contains the following columns:

PositionID, PortfolioCode, SecurityAccount, Custodian, Quantity

Users must be able to retrieve Quantities consolidated by some predefined set of columns e.g. {PortfolioCode, SecurityAccount}, {Porfolio, Custodian}

First, I simply used dynamic queries in my application code but, as the database grew, the queries became slower.

I wonder if it would be a good idea to add another table that will contain the consolidated quantities. I guess it depends on the distribution of those groups?

Besides, how to synchronize the source table with the consolidated one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL Server you could use indexed views to do this, it'd keep the aggregates synchronised with the underlying table, but would slow down inserts to the underlying table:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx

If it's purely a count of grouped rows in a single table, would standard indexing not suffice here? More info on your structure would be useful.

Edit: Also, it sounds a little like you're using your OLTP server as a reporting server? If so, have you considered whether a data warehouse and an ETL process might be appropriate?

Comment: I cannot introduce another technology at this point in the project. The indexed views should do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: One more thing: what if I need the indexed view to be in relation with other tables?

Comment: @rlesias, not sure what you mean by "In relation to other tables" - But if you mean joining across tables and indexing the results of that, then you can do that. The minor difficulties would be: You can't build the indexes online, so it might block tables while you create it (Deployment might need downtime), and an indexed view is schema-bound (So you'd need to drop it and recreate it if you needed to change the structure of the underlying tables).

Comment: I have a Comments table that has no meaning in the context of a single Position but should be related to GroupedPositions. I cannot create a relation between Comments and GroupedPositions if GroupedPositions is a view, can I?

Comment: You can't create referential integrity to a view, no. That's true for normal views and for indexed views. You can join to the view, if that's what you mean? SELECT Columns FROM MyTable AS T INNER JOIN MyView AS V on T.GroupId = V.Id would work. Do let me know what it is you're trying to achieve? :)

Comment: Yes a simple join should do the trick. Thank you for your help!